# Retrieve the sum of the top n-4 points per name mySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, database

How can I retrieve the sum of the top n-4 points per name. Can we do this in one SQL statement without using user defined session variables?

Input:
Look below or [Here (clearer pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87hmb.png)

Output:
Look below or [Here (clearer pic)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i6yZ0.png)

Summary: 
Jeff = 7+5+4+4 = 20 
Kat = 8+5+5+4 = 22 
Neil = 10+7+5+0 = 22 
Rick = 9+8+3+2 = 22

Input Database:
±-----±-----------±-------+ 
| Name | assignment | points |
±-----±-----------±-------+
| Jeff | 1 | 7 |
| Jeff | 2 | 5 |
| Jeff | 3 | 3 |
| Jeff | 4 | 4 |
| Jeff | 5 | 4 |
| Kat | 1 | 4 |
| Kat | 2 | 8 |
| Kat | 3 | 5 |
| Kat | 4 | 3 |
| Kat | 5 | 5 |
| Neil | 1 | 5 |
| Neil | 2 | 7 |
| Neil | 3 | 10 |
| Neil | 4 | 0 |
| Neil | 5 | 0 |
| Rick | 1 | 2 |
| Rick | 2 | 1 |
| Rick | 3 | 8 |
| Rick | 4 | 3 |
| Rick | 5 | 9 |
±-----±-----------±-------+

Output:
±-----±-----------±-------+ 
| Name | assignment | points |
±-----±-----------±-------+
| Jeff | 20 |
| Kat | 22 |
| Neil | 22 |
| Rick | 22 |
 
±-----±-----------±-------+

Thank you!!

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution in MySQL 8+ is:

```
select name, sum(points)
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by name order by points desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum <= 4
group by name;
```

In earlier versions of MySQL you need to do more work.  It would seem that something like this would solve your problem:

```
select t.name, sum(t.points)
from t
where t.assignment in (select t2.assignment
                       from t t2
                       where t2.name = t.name
                       order by t2.points desc
                       limit 4
                      )
group by t.name;
```

But MySQL does not allow this syntax.  If you had no duplicates for points, then this would work:

```
select t.name, sum(t.points)
from t
where t.points >= coalesce( (select t2.points
                             from t t2
                             where t2.name = t.name
                             order by t2.points desc
                             limit 1 offset 3
                            ), 0)
group by t.name;
```

But if the 4th and 5th row have the same points, then you will have more than 4 rows in the sum.

Now, you could solve this using variables . . . but instead, we can adapt the last solution:

```
select t.name,
       (case when count(*) = 4 then sum(t.points)
             else sum(t.points) - (count(*) - 4) * min(t.points)
        end)
from t
where t.points >= coalesce( (select t2.points
                             from t t2
                             where t2.name = t.name
                             order by t2.points desc
                             limit 1 offset 3
                            ), 0)
group by t.name;
```

This takes into account any ties.  Strictly speaking, the `case` is not necessary, but I think it makes the logic explicit.

EDIT:

If you want all but the bottom four (your question isn't clear), the same method works:

```
select t.name,
       (case when count(*) = 4 then sum(t.points)
             else sum(t.points) - (count(*) - 4) * min(t.points)
        end)
from t
where t.points >= coalesce( (select t2.points
                             from t t2
                             where t2.name = t.name
                             order by t2.points asc
                             limit 1 offset 3
                            ), 0)
group by t.name;
```

The only difference is reversing the order by.

Comment: Just wondering if MySQL does not allow `LIMIT` inside a subquery; why would it allow inside `Coalesce()` ? +1

Comment: Hi, thank you, im pretty sure this returns the first 4 elements, not n-4 (n being the number of assignments)